# Django child-parent template relation

Tags: python, django, django-templates

**Suppose I have**

- mainprofile.html which I render from views.profile and
- followers.html which I render from views.followers

When I click on the followers button, it calls views.followers 
and renders followers and plugs it into the mainprofile correctly.

**What I want to do:**

When I do that, I lose all the profile information on the parent page (mainprofile) such as userinfo.username
How can I overcome this?

mainprofile.html:

```
{% extends 'layout/master.html' %}
    {% load sharedtags %}

    {% block content %}

        {{ userinfo.username }}

        ...some profile information...

        followers_button

        {% block right_side_main_layout %}

            ... some info ...

        {% endblock right_side_main%}

    {% endblock content%}
```

followers.html:

```
{% extends 'mainprofile.html' %}
{% block right_side_main_layout %}

    ... list of followers ...

{% endblock right_side_main_layout %}
```

views.py:

```
def profile(request,username):

    userdetail  = AuthUser.objects.filter(username=username) 

    template='profil/mainprofile.html'
    context = RequestContext(request, {'userinfo': userdetail })
    return render_to_response(template, context)

def followers(request, username):

    followers  = Followers.objects.filter(username=username)  

    template = 'profil/em-profile-follower.html'
    context = RequestContext(request,{'followers': followers})
    return direct_to_template(template,context)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add the AuthUser instance also to the `followers` view.

```
def followers(request, username):

    followers  = Followers.objects.filter(username=username)  
    userdetail  = AuthUser.objects.filter(username=username) 

    template = 'profil/em-profile-follower.html'
    context = RequestContext(request,{'followers': followers, 'userinfo': userdetail})
    return direct_to_template(template,context)
```

Now you'll also have the userinfo in this template (and view)

I'm not sure how your model looks. But I assume that AuthUser has a ForeignKeyField(Follower).
If you give this field a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) (like 'followers'), you can do this:

`userdetail = AuthUser.objects.filter(username=username)`

and in your template you can then access your followers by doing:
`userdetail.followers`